# jwt.decode - qual a necessidade de uma lista de algoritmos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jwt

Estou estudando Python e precisava resolver um exercício usando JWT (JSON Web Tokens).

Era necessário criar um token e verificar a validade, buscando códigos de exemplo, encontrei na própria documentação [algumas opções](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) que atenderam facilmente a necessidade.

Nos exemplos de uso do *jwt.decode* destaco dois exemplos:

1. `decoded = jwt.decode(encoded, public_key, algorithms='RS256')`
2. ```
   try:
        jwt.decode('JWT_STRING', 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
   except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        # Signature has expired
   ```

O curioso é o parâmetro *algorithms* que pode tanto receber um algoritmo como uma lista. Nesse ponto, em uma revisão de código que um colega fez, chegamos nessa questão:

Qual a necessidade de uma lista de algoritmos?

A lista seria para "tentar" decodificar em todas formas passadas para o *algorithms*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No caso dessa biblioteca em específico, de acordo com a documentação:

> When decoding, you can also specify which algorithms you would like to permit when validating the JWT by using the algorithms parameter which takes a list of allowed algorithms.

<sup>[Fonte.](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/algorithms.html#specifying-an-algorithm)</sup>

Ou seja, enquanto você estiver decodificando um JWT, você pode também especificar quais algoritmos você quer permitir durante a validação do token.

Por exemplo, se você passar `['HS512', 'HS256']` para o argumento `algorithms` do método `decode`, ele será capaz de validar os tokens codificados com os algoritmos `HS512` e `HS256`.

> A lista seria para "tentar" decodificar em todas formas passadas para o algorithms?

Nesse caso, acho que "tentar" é uma palavra incorreta, já que o próprio token JWT especifica qual algoritmo foi usado durante a sua criação. Portanto, a lista serve para dizer quais algoritmos podem ser usados para decodificar o dado token.

Comment: Captei a ideia!

Answer (score -1):

A lista de algoritmos que é passado como parâmetro ao realizar um decode informa quais algoritmos são permitidos para realizar a verificação do token e assim retornar as declarações utilizadas durante a geração do mesmo.

[Referência](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jwt.decode)